# how to enable/disable a div tag and all elements inside it when a button is click? javascript only

Tags: javascript

```js
function toggleDisabled(el) {
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    }
    catch(E){
    }
    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
            el.style.opacity=0.5;
            toggleDisabled(el.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been able to disable the button onclick, but I'm having trouble getting the other button to re-enable it..one more thing it is not the button that will enable/disable, but rather it is the div and its elements.

Heres the link :http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/20/

Try to click the text, then call, it will both disabled, my problem is I don't want them to be both disabled or both enabled...

Comment: `<div>`s cannot be enabled or disabled...

Comment: i mean the elements inside it, in my case i want to disable the form inside it with two iput boxes and a textarea..

Comment: http://javascript.about.com/library/bldisable.htm

Comment: @mooseman:ive updated my post and added the link..please try to look it up and see if you could do something with my problem...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is -- I went to your JSfiddle and your elements are disabling correctly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @aug:for example i press the text, it should be enabled and the other should be disabled then if i press the call it will be enabled and the other should be disabled..get it?